# How can I select a class in a class in css?

Tags: html, css

[Here's the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfb6h.jpg)

So what I'm trying to do is that I want to give The Business Man and The Lamplighter border individually.

Since both are in a container I figured I can just use .container.asteroid but it's not working.

Anyone got an answer to this?

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that everyone can understand it properly. [see why you shouldn't post image as a code or an error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Comment: add space btw  .container and .asteroid =>  .container .asteroid

Answer (score 3):

You need to put space between the two class names.

```
.container .asteroid{

}
```

Here's how to give style to specific .asteroid class in your html.

```
.container .asteroid{
    border:green solid 1px;
}

.container .asteroid.big{
    border:red solid 1px;
}
```

Comment: @ricsi114 .. If the above answer was helpful, an upvote will make my day. :) and also mark it as answer. :)

Comment: please combine your 2 answers into a single answer :-)